# use Blat to send mail in local network problem

Tags: blat

I am trying to use Blat to send mail in the local mail server but an error message keeps returning, saying that the SMTP server does not like the sender name.

I have kept trying with different sender names but it's still the same. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've used blat for sometime to do this.  here's the key.

```
-to 1@foo.bar -f 2@foo.bar -server your.smtp.server-name.bar
```

what are you using?